# New Mobile Version of Facebook on Iphone doesn't follow default page listed in Fan Page

Tags: iphone, mobile, qr-code, facebook-page, fan-page

Up until about 2 weeks ago, if you visited a Facebook Fan Page on an Iphone through safari (not the Facebook App), it brought you to the normal internet version of the site.  This made it very easy to have control over what people saw first when they visited the page by creating an app and then specifying the app related tab (page) as the default landing page for users.

In this way you could include a "like / reveal" (Fan Gate) page and have the same type of incentive and offer translate directly to the iphone viewers as it had been seen on the internet using a computer. (still not sure how it looks on Android)

Since they added the redirect that forwards mobile browsers to their m.facebook.com page, if you try going to a specific fan page, it brings you to the "Wall" as the default and doesn't seem to even show the special tabs you created through an app -completely ignoring what ever defaults you had set up in the app!

Has anybody figured out a way to have a mobile browser pay attention to the default page named in the app or somehow disable the mobile browser redirect so it goes to the standard page.  This is very important for using with QR codes, since you used to just link the QR directly to the fanpage address and it worked pefect, but now simply leaves the people a little confused about the offer you were promoting.

Thanks for any help on this!!!!!

Comment: We just tried creating an iframe reference within another page directly to the Facebook Fan Page thinking that it might not auto redirect if it was loading within another page.  No such luck...  Apparently their servers can tell what you're doing and it sends the user to the Fan Page Wall anyway.    At this point, I'm thinking I might have to build a small mobile page that has a similar offer to my Fan Page Fan Gate and just throw a Fan Box in the code so they can easily like you too.  Facebook People!!!  How can I set up Fan Page Likes with QR codes if no one can see the Fan Gate??????????

Comment: If you don't know the answer and are equally baffled, please feel free to vote this up so it gets more exposure.  Thanks!!!!